# How do I export a text file with strings on different lines?

Tags: export

I would like to `Export` a text file, and use paragraph / ENTER commands to place different strings on different lines.  Say we have three strings - str1, str2, and str3.  How can we place them on separate lines of a text file?  This command -

```
Export["test.txt", StringJoin[str1, str2, str3]];
```

Places str1, str2, and str3 on a single line.

Comment: Try `Export["test.txt",{str1, str2, str3}]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Works.  Terrific.  But is there a general way to specify some line depth for each string?

Comment: How do you define "line depth"?

Comment: @Anon I define line depth as the line # in a text file.  For example "a" [ENTER] "b" [ENTER] [ENTER] "c" would place "c" at a so-called line depth of 4 (since it's four lines down from the top of the file).

Comment: OK, just making sure. You can put elements "" instead of strings in the list. E.g. `{str1,"","",str2}` will make the line depth of str2 be 4. If you say how you intend to indicate on what line a string should appear, such a list could be generated programmatically.

Comment: For example: `{{1,str1},{4,str2}}` could be a way to format such data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following will work for you.

```
str[1] = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
str[2] = "Grumpy wizards make a toxic brew for the jovial queen";
str[3] = "The five boxing wizards jumped quickly";

text = Normal[SparseArray[{1 -> str[1], 2 -> str[2], 5 -> str[3]}]] /. {0 -> ""}

Export[FileNameJoin[{HomeDirectory[], "Desktop", "test.txt"}], text]
```

The contents of test.txt will look like this:

> ```
> The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog  
> Grumpy wizards make a toxic brew for the jovial queen  
>
>
> The five boxing wizards jumped quickly
> ```

#### Edit

If the strings are indexed by line number, as Yves Klett suggests, then this very simple code will suffice:

```
str[1] = "line 1"; str[2] = "line 2"; str[5] = "line 5";
text = Table[str[i], {i, 5}] /. str[_] -> ""
```

Mr.Wizard has come up with an even more concise variant of the above.

```
str[_] = ""; text = Array[str, 5]
```

#### Another edit

Mr.Wizard has also supplied a neat variant of my original `SparseArray`solution.

```
Normal @ SparseArray[{1 -> str[1], 2 -> str[2], 5 -> str[3]}, Automatic, ""]
```

Comment: neat use of sparse arrays +1

Comment: How about directly using the line number as argument of `str`? Saves on wear and tear during automation...

Comment: @YvesKlett. Good idea. I've edited my answer to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: I think this can be cleaned up even further: `str[_] = "";
text = Array[str, 5]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I take it that your comment is intended to apply only to the case considered int the edit.

Comment: Yes. . . . . . .

Comment: While I've got you making edits here's another to consider: `Normal @ SparseArray[{1 -> str[1], 2 -> str[2], 5 -> str[3]}, Automatic, ""]` -- I think this is a bit cleaner though not quite as concise.  Do as you see fit of course.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use the newline command "\n" and have the complete file in a single string. For the example above:

```
str = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog\nGrumpy wizards make a toxic brew for the jovial queen\n\n\nThe five boxing wizards jumped quickly";
Export["test.txt", str]
```

gives the text file

[image]